# Eradicate the error - 'bool' obj can't be iterated

Tags: python, list

The code intends to print a frequency table for a random input discrete data. Here's the code :

```
from math import log10
from random import randint
N = int(input("Enter number of observations:\n"))
l = [ randint(1,100) for var in range (N) ]
print(l)
l.sort()
print(l)
k = 1 + (3.332*log10(N))
k1 = round(k)
print ("Number of intervals should be = ",k1)
x = N//k1 + 1
print("S.No\t\tIntervals\t\tFrequency")
c = 1 #count
while c <= k:
    a = (c-1)*x
    b = c*x
    count = 0
    for v in range(a,b) in l:
        count += 1

    print(c,"\t\t","{}-{}".format(a,b),"\t\t",count)
    c += 1
```

This shows the above cited error, how to resolve this?

Comment: Your problem is with the line `for v in range(a,b) in l:` the second `in` causes the interpreter to evaluate the expression `range(a,b) in l` which is a logical test for whether the `range(a,b)` is a member of the list `l`. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that range(a,b) sets up a list of integers from a to b-1. What you are asking for is for the code to go through l and pick out numbers matching those criteria, which looks instead like:

```
for v in l:
    if ((v>=a) and (v<b)):
        count += 1
```

If you really want to use range, and your data are going to stay integers, then it would look like:

```
for v in l:
    if v in range(int(a),int(b)):
        count += 1
```

Also

```
x = N//k1 + 1
```

should be

```
x = 100//k1 + 1
```

Comment: probably better to say while c <= k1: